# Executing command line program (Abaqus-python script) from python script

Tags: python, subprocess, abaqus

I am trying to run an Abaqus-python script file from another python script executed in Spyder (python 3.7, windows 10).

If I run the following command in CMD
`abaqus cae -noGUI model.py`
the code executes as expected. However, if I try to run `cp = subprocess.run('abaqus cae -noGUI model.py',shell=True)`
I don't get any output. Below is what is returned in cp.

[image]

Notes:

1. The Abaqus-python file I am trying to run is in the same folder as the python script I have.
2. I have tried various sp.call, sp.run, os.systems in different string and list formats.
3. "C:\Abaqus\Commands" and "C:\SIMULIA\Commands" are both in my PATH environment variable.
4. I think the -noGUI call is important to the problem. I can't seem to find others on SO with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of digging, I think the issue is that the PATH for my python install is done thought Anaconda so I have a different path this vs CMD. I fixed this by adding the full Abaqus location to the command. See below.

subprocess.call(r'C:\SIMULIA\Commands\abaqus job=Job-1 ask_delete=OFF interactive', shell=True)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your problem is due to, but note that Abaqus scripting is based on python 2.7, therefore you might need to downgrade it

Comment: Thanks, but this is calling Abaqus as a program, so when I call Abaqus it will run python commands in its own environment and return data to data files. So, there is no cross-contamination between the python environments.